# How do I define CSS class in an Inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a popup screen appear when i click on an icon in my profile page of a game. The developers have given us access to use HTML codes in our profile area, though using the STYLE tags are blocked. Also I have no access to the head section of the HTML codes, as a result I cannot create any external file to define CSS class and link them to the profile page.

Below I have created an example of my codes. In the example code I have created an external CSS code. I want to know how can I get those external CSS into my HTML code (Using Inline CSS method). My problem is defining the CSS class in an Inline CSS method.

**Things to know before answering my question:**

1) Cant create an external file for CSS.

2) Cant write codes inside the HEAD tags.

3) Cant use the STYLE tag.

4) Only HTML codes are allowed. BBCodes are not allowed.

**My HTML code looks like this:**

```
<p>
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">
  <img src="SOME ICON URL HERE">
 </a>
</p>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay light">
 <a class="cancel" href="#"></a>
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>TITLE</h2>
  <div class="content">
   <p>PARAGRAPH ONE GOES HERE</p>
   <p>PARAGRAPH TWO GOES HERE</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**My external CSS code looks like this:**

```
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: opacity 200ms;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 &.light {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }
 .cancel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
 }
 &:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

.popup {
 margin: 75px auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 width: 300px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
 .light & {
  border-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 }
 h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 .close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  &:hover {
   opacity: 1;
  }
 }
 .content {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  &:last-child {
  margin: 0;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `style` attributes?

Comment: Well you'll have to replace every single class by an inline `style` attribute... This is clearly horrible. Ask for at least the `HEAD`

Comment: Classes cannot be *defined* inline...you can't do what it is you are trying to do. You need more access from the developers.

Comment: What about javascript?

Comment: Use a `script` element which inserts a stylesheet? And if `script` elements are forbidden, what about a JS injection like `<img src="//" onerror="JS code" />`?

Comment: as intriguing as it is to hack a solution, it sounds very shady to me.

Answer (score 4):

you'll have to do something like this, using the html inline style

```
<div id="popup1" style="<!-- styles here -->">
   <!-- other code here -->
</div>
```

Comment: HTML inline styling doesn't allow calling of classes attached to that div or whatever the styles are on. The styles applied inline can only apply to that particular line. That's why inline styling isn't a great option. in order to do what you want, you'll have to get more permissions from the clients. A JS injection might work as was suggested earlier, but that probably isn't a great option either. I would definetely request more permissions